# How to add users to Docker container?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have a docker container with some processes (uwsgi and celery) running inside. I want to create a celery user and a uwsgi user for these processes as well as a worker group that they will both belong to, in order to assign permissions.

I tried adding `RUN adduser uwsgi` and `RUN adduser celery` to my Dockerfile, but this is causing problems, since these commands prompt for input (I've posted the responses from the build below).

What is the best way to add users to a Docker container so as to set permissions for workers running in the container?

My Docker image is built from the official Ubuntu14.04 base.

Here is the output from the Dockerfile when the adduser commands are run:

```
Adding user `uwsgi' ...
Adding new group `uwsgi' (1000) ... 
Adding new user `uwsgi' (1000) with group `uwsgi' ... 
Creating home directory `/home/uwsgi' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ... 
[91mEnter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: [0m 
[91mpasswd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
[0m 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 563.
[0m 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 564.
[0m 
Try again? [y/N] 
Changing the user information for uwsgi
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
Room Number []:     Work Phone []:  Home Phone []:  Other []: 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 589.
[0m 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 590.
[0m 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] 
---> 258f2f2f13df 
Removing intermediate container 59948863162a 
Step 5 : RUN adduser celery 
---> Running in be06f1e20f64 
Adding user `celery' ...
Adding new group `celery' (1001) ... 
Adding new user `celery' (1001) with group `celery' ... 
Creating home directory `/home/celery' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ... 
[91mEnter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: [0m 
[91mpasswd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
[0m 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 563.
[0m 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 564.
[0m 
Try again? [y/N] 
Changing the user information for celery
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []:   Room Number []:     Work Phone []: 
Home Phone []:  Other []: 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in chop at /usr/sbin/adduser line 589.
[0m 
[91mUse of uninitialized value $answer in pattern match (m//) at /usr/sbin/adduser line 590.
[0m 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 830, accepted):

The trick is to use `useradd` instead of its interactive wrapper `adduser`.
I usually create users with:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
```

which creates a home directory for the user and ensures that bash is the default shell.

You can then add:

```
USER newuser
WORKDIR /home/newuser
```

to your dockerfile. Every command afterwards as well as interactive sessions will be executed as user `newuser`:

```
docker run -t -i image
newuser@131b7ad86360:~$
```

You might have to give `newuser` the permissions to execute the programs you intend to run before invoking the user command.

Using non-privileged users inside containers is a good idea for security reasons. It also has a few drawbacks. Most importantly, people deriving images from your image will have to switch back to root before they can execute commands with superuser privileges.

Comment: Is 'newuser' the name of the user which you yourself will select?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Replace it with a name of your choice.

Comment: I'd recommend using the full name options in a Dockerfile, like in a script, instead of the short ones (more to be used when used interactively IMO).

`useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash` is more understandable/readable for coworkers.

Comment: In order to set password you could use chpasswd like: `RUN echo 'newuser:newpassword' | chpasswd`

Comment: Note that if you're creating a new user with a large user ID, docker may hang/crash as it tries to create *lastlog* - a massive sparse file. Avoid this with the `--no-log-init` option to `useradd`.

Comment: Nice tip, @iuridiniz! Don't forget to call it before `USER newuser`. If you also need the user to have root privileges, you can also include `adduser <username> sudo`.

Comment: @Yamaneko yes or for adding to groups the non-interactive version `useradd` as suggested already in the original answer.

Comment: So useradd does the job but how can we handle other commands in docker which requires an interactive prompt.What could be the general solution in that case?

Comment: how can you give this user sudo?

Comment: `/bin/sh: useradd: not found` alpine linux

Comment: @deathangel908 It's available in the `shadow` package: `apk add shadow`. See 
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.8/community/x86/shadow

Comment: Is this only for Linux? Or can we also adduser in Windows?

Comment: @deathangel908 in alpine try `adduser` command, eg. `RUN adduser -D -g '' newuser`

Comment: I get `useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.` .. and I cannot use `sudo` as then I obviously get `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

Comment: how do you add this user to a specific group?

Answer (score 257):

#### Ubuntu

Try the following lines in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/ubuntu -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 ubuntu
USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
```

`useradd` options (see: `man useradd`):

- `-r`, `--system` Create a system account. <sup>see: [Implications creating *system accounts*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213101/21471)</sup>
- `-m`, `--create-home` Create the user's home directory.
- `-d`, `--home-dir HOME_DIR` Home directory of the new account.
- `-s`, `--shell SHELL` Login shell of the new account.
- `-g`, `--gid GROUP` Name or ID of the primary group.
- `-G`, `--groups GROUPS` List of supplementary groups.
- `-u`, `--uid UID` Specify user ID. <sup>see: [Understanding how uid and gid work in Docker containers](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf)</sup>
- `-p`, `--password PASSWORD` Encrypted password of the new account (e.g. `ubuntu`).

#### Setting default user's password

To set the user password, add `-p "$(openssl passwd -1 ubuntu)"` to `useradd` command.

Alternatively add the following lines to your `Dockerfile`:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
RUN echo 'ubuntu:ubuntu' | chpasswd
```

The first [shell instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) is to make sure that `-o pipefail` option is enabled before `RUN` with a pipe in it. Read more: [Hadolint: Linting your Dockerfile](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/hadolint-linting-your-dockerfile/).

Comment: Why would the user be in the root group? Isn't the whole point of this is to have a non-root user for security purposes

Comment: @Novaterata Depending on the use. `root` group doesn't indicate they've root access, it just they've more read access to some files (such as logs), which is useful, but it depends on the project.

Comment: I can see that this works, I automatically am logged in as user, but I'm still generating files owned by root. I even just used 'USER user' since my username on the local user and group is 'user'. Still generates root owned files. Is there something else I should be doing? I'm basically making a docker container that compiles our codebase. So it checks out code from svn, sets up variables using bash source. Could bash commands be doing things as root even if I'm never asked for the root password?

Comment: Setting the password interactively with ```SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
RUN echo 'ubuntu:ubuntu' | chpasswd``` didn't work for me, the container was just built, didn't ask me for the password. What did I do wrong?

Comment: For security I recommend `-p "$(openssl passwd -6 YOUR_PASS_HERE)"`. The `-1` option uses MD5-based hash that is insecure (in case of db leak).

Answer (score 121):

To avoid the interactive questions by adduser, you can call it with these parameters:

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' newuser
```

The `--gecos` parameter is used to set the additional information. In this case it is just empty.

On systems with busybox (like Alpine), use

```
RUN adduser -D -g '' newuser
```

See [busybox adduser](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#adduser)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like `adduser` high-level solution is generally preferred to using low-level functions like `useradd`.

Comment: `adduser: unrecognized option: gecos` This doesn't seem to work on Alpine.

Comment: what does the --disabled-password do and how can we set password to the user at the same time in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 39):

Adding user in docker and running your app under that user is very good practice for security point of view. To do that I would recommend below steps:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Copy source to container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/src

# Copy source code
COPY src /usr/app/src
COPY package.json /usr/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/app

WORKDIR /usr/app

# Running npm install for production purpose will not run dev dependencies.
RUN npm install -only=production    

# Create a user group 'xyzgroup'
RUN addgroup -S xyzgroup

# Create a user 'appuser' under 'xyzgroup'
RUN adduser -S -D -h /usr/app/src appuser xyzgroup

# Chown all the files to the app user.
RUN chown -R appuser:xyzgroup /usr/app

# Switch to 'appuser'
USER appuser

# Open the mapped port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the process
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Above steps is a full example of the copying NodeJS project files, creating a user group and user, assigning permissions to the user for the project folder, switching to the newly created user and running the app under that user.

Comment: addgroup failed for me,

Step 11/15 : RUN addgroup -S username
 ---> Running in db9fd22d469d
Option s is ambiguous (shell, system)
adduser [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
[--firstuid ID] [--lastuid ID] [--gecos GECOS] [--ingroup GROUP | --gid ID]
[--disabled-password] [--disabled-login] [--encrypt-home] USER
   Add a normal user

Comment: Thank-you!  After many attempts this was the one that worked for me

Comment: -S is amiguous (shell or system)

Answer (score 30):

You can imitate open source Dockerfile, for example:

Node:   [node12-github](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/6bae0eb339bc5be880f01b652f48fdf939f76590/12/buster/Dockerfile)

```
RUN groupadd --gid 1000 node \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid node --shell /bin/bash --create-home node
```

superset:   [superset-github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/contrib/docker/Dockerfile)

```
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --no-log-init --shell /bin/bash 
    superset
```

I think it's a good way to follow open source.

Answer (score 18):

Everyone has their personal favorite, and this is mine:

```
RUN useradd --user-group --system --create-home --no-log-init app
USER app
```

Reference: [**man useradd**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) ([**alt**](https://dashdash.io/8/useradd))

The `RUN` line above will add the user and group `app`:

```bash
root@ef3e54b60048:/# id app
uid=999(app) gid=999(app) groups=999(app)
```

Use a more specific name than `app` if the image is to be reused as a base image. As an aside, include `--shell /bin/bash` if you really need.

---

Partial credit: [answer by Ryan M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57321205/)

Comment: This answer was the only one that worked for me.  Using FROM python:3.9.6-bullseye

Comment: @ArkhamAngel because `bullseye` is a release of `debian`, `alpine` will be a bit different. I really like this answer, cause it is not using shorthand args

Comment: It worked for me wtih python3:12 slim

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can do like this.

```
RUN addgroup demo && adduser -DH -G demo demo
```

First command creates group called **demo**. Second command creates **demo** user and adds him to previously created **demo** group.

Flags stands for:

```
-G Group
-D Don't assign password
-H Don't create home directory
```

Comment: P.S This command might slightly vary base on a Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly add below entries inside dockerfile in order to create a sudo user in container.

```
RUN useradd -m  -s /bin/bash ubuntu
RUN usermod -aG sudo ubuntu && echo "ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu // should be 0440
USER ubuntu:ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WORKDIR /api

RUN adduser -D nameuser

COPY --from=builder --chown=nameuser:nameuser /api

USER nameuser
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your Dockerfile (You can run any linux command this way)

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash yourNewUserName
```