# Privileges in an Ubuntu Docker container after USER statement in Dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker, root, dockerfile

I created a Dockerfile

```
FROM       ubuntu:latest
```

as the parent image.

Later the Dockerfile creates a new group and user without sudo privileges via

```
RUN groupadd -r myappuser -g 433
RUN useradd -u 431 -r -g myappuser -d /opt/myapp -s /bin/false -c "my app user" myappuser
```

Before executing the application I switch to this new

```
USER       myappuser
```

Question: Does this setting make it possible to gain root privileges again once the image is build and the container is running (with e.g. `docker exec -it`)?

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27703359/1725096

Comment: just a though, can you add the user to sudoers or is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Since this user is dedicated for running the main application it should not have full privileges ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use sudo, you could have a Dockerfile without `USER` (so it runs the command as root) and `CMD` pointing to a script that does the user switching, that way a `docker exec` would run as root.

Other way is to set the root password and use `su`.
An example of doing that is in the tutum images

https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-centos/blob/master/set_root_pw.sh