# Authorization settings problems for tomcat while deploying with docker

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, docker

I am new here and also new to the docker and tomcat. I am trying to deploy a maven project with docker. I have managed to create an image for tomcat in docker and created a container from that image. https://0.0.0.0:49153// or https://172.17.42.1:49153/ gives me the apache tomcat opening page; but whenever i try to enter to the web manager; i can not login with my own username and password for my local tomcat.

I guess i need to add the tomcat-users.xml configurations to my docker image but i don't know how to set a user for that. Here is my dockerfile

`FROM tomcat:7-jre7
MAINTAINER "rozerinaktas <rozerinaktas@gmail.com>"
// there should be an add command here i think
CMD sudo service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out`

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: This is (borderline) off topic, it seems more to do with application server configuration than with programming; on the other hand it is used to deploy a self build application that uses Maven. Still, I think it has a better place at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: how can i set the configurations?

Comment: if you need a user, create it with the USER directive in your Dockerfile, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user, and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/add-user-to-docker-container

Comment: what im trying to achieve is to open web manager for tomcat from docker. my local tomcat server works a specific username and password but when i try to login with the same parameters, i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to see how can you set a user name and password for the tomcat server. In case there is a config file, you need to mount it using the -v option into the docker container or you can copy it into the container by specifying the relevant COPY command in the Dockerfile . Read up regarding this on the official page of tomcat server on the docker hub. I am sure they must have mentioned something related to setting default username and password.

I had a similar problem for MySQL. It was mentioned clearly that we can provide the default password for the user "root" for MySQL as an environment variable passed during the `docker-run` command or in the Dockerfile itself.

Comment: Where will i copy my tomcat-users.xml file in dockerfile? What is the path for that? Can you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: i edited my dockerfile and everytime i try to run a new container it says ;

/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found

This is my new dockerfile 
FROM tomcat:7-jre7
MAINTAINER "rozerinaktas <rozerinaktas@gmail.com>"

RUN adduser newuser 
RUN passwd newuser 


CMD sudo service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out

Comment: Can you also tell the command you are running for spinning up the container ? And as for the sudo part, it is possible that the base image for the tomcat:7-jre7 does not understand sudo. It might have some parts of the linux kernel but not all of them. So don't use sudo. Run directy.

Comment: you were right i added the sudo package into the dockerfile and made a few more changes and it worked :)