# Files created inside docker are write protected on host

Tags: ember.js, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker container for rails and ember.I am mounting the source from my local to the container. All the changes I make here on local are reflected in the container.

Now I want to use `generators` to create files. The files are created, but they are write protected on my machine.

When I try to do `docker-compose run frontend bash`, I get a `root@061e4159d4ef:/frontend#` superuser prompt access inside of the container. I can create files when I am in this mode. These files are write protected in my host.

I have also tried `docker-compose run --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" frontend bash`, I get a `I have no name!@31bea5ae977c:/frontend$`, I am unable to create any file in this mode. Below is the error message that I get.

```
I have no name!@31bea5ae977c:/frontend$ ember g template about
/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                    throw err0;
                    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.config'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:916:18)
    at sync (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at Object.create.all.get (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:39:13)
    at Object.Configstore (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
    at clientId (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:22:21)
    at module.exports (/frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:65:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember:26:3
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:6.2

ENV INSTALL_PATH /frontend
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

# Copy package.json separately so it's recreated when package.json
# changes.
COPY package.json ./package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . $INSTALL_PATH
RUN npm  install -g phantomjs bower ember-cli ;\
    bower --allow-root install

EXPOSE 4200
EXPOSE 49152

CMD [ "ember", "server" ]
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file, please note it is not in the current directory, but the parent.

```
frontend:
   build: "frontend/"
   dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
   environment:
      - EMBER_ENV=development
   ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "49152:49152"
   volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
```

I want to know, how can I use generateors? I am new to learning docker. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using boot2docker ?

Comment: No Im using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the `I have no name!` because of this: `$(id -u):$(id -g)`
The user id and group in your host are not linked to any user in your container.

Solution:

Execute `chown UID:GID -R /frontend` **inside** the container if its already running and you cannot stop it for some reason. Otherwise you could just do the chown command in the host and then run your container again. Node that UID and GID **must** belong to a user inside the container

Example: `chown 101:101 -R /frontend` with 101 is the UID:GID of www-data.

If there are no other user exept root in your container, you will have to create a new one. To do so you must create a Dockerfile and put something like this:

```
FROM your_image_name
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
```

More information about Dockerfiles can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/builder/) or just by googlin' it.

Comment: What do you mean by cannot stop out for some reason?

Comment: I don't know, if you're in production or something.

Comment: No it is on development. For this it seems that I'll have to create a user inside the container corresponding to my local user.

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya Yes, you should. You don't have any other options. You'll have to create a Dockerfile in which you create that user. I'm updating my answer if you don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Fares this workflow doesn't seem natural to me. Docker meant to be portable and used  any where. This doesn't allow my other developers to integrate easily. There is another way I am trying that out too. If that doesn't work, I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya Creating a new user still makes things portable and easy to integrate. It takes about one minute to do this...

Comment: Yes, It seems I was thinking about terminal session execution.
[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/add-user-to-docker-container) completes it.