# Non-root user in Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
USER test
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

For this Dockerfile, I want to be able to create a user without a password, and when the Docker container is run, I want that user to be used, instead of root. When I try to run the container, `docker run -it test:1`, I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user test: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

How can I create a user in a Dockerfile and have that user be the default user when the container is run interactively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add User to Docker Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/add-user-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `RUN useradd -s /bin/bash user` before the **USER** directive.

Comment: That worked and did exactly what I wanted it to do, thanks!

Comment: Is this only on Linux? Or same in Windows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Windows.

Comment: @variable on Windows, you can follow the instructions from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user, i.e. `net user /add my_user`