# Add vsftpd user directory using single Dockerfile and set password

Tags: docker

Hello i am a beginner in Docker. 
I just wanted to add user for ftp server so i used command "adduser lal". As it is interactive console, it will ask for password. But how to follow this step in single Dockerfile. My docker looks like:

```
# getting base image debian
FROM debian


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y s3fs

RUN apt-get install -y vsftpd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ftp
RUN cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.orig
RUN adduser lal
RUN mkdir /home/lal/ftp
RUN chown nobody:nogroup /home/lal/ftp
RUN chmod a-w /home/lal/ftp
RUN mkdir /home/lal/ftp/files
RUN chown lal:lal /home/lal/ftp/files


CMD [ "echo","Hello World...! from my first docker image" ]
```

It would be helpful for me if you give any advise regarding my Dockerfile too. Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add user to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/add-user-to-docker-container)

Comment: @leopal this question helps to create user but how can i set password for it. Because i have to use this user to upload file in S3 Bucket as FTP.

Comment: Learn basic Linux commands: `echo lal:newpassword' | chpasswd`

Comment: @emix how to use "echo lal:newpassword' | chpasswd". Should i use it like RUN echo lal:newpassword | chpasswd ?

Comment: Didn't you try already?