# RUN addgroup / adduser. Get: Option s is ambiguous (shell, system) error

Tags: docker

I am Dockerising my first flask app and following [an online guide](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-flask-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) but stuck with the following line in `Dockerfile.prod`.

`RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app`

I get the error `Option s is ambiguous (shell, system)`

I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/how-to-add-users-to-docker-container) and tried the accepted answer (pretty much the same):

`RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup`

With the same outcome. I have tried specifying `--shell` and `--system`, and `--group` instead get the error `addgroup: Only one or two names allowed.`

No matter what I try, I get these errors:
`Option s is ambiguous (shell, system)`
`Option g is ambiguous (gecos, gid, group)`

I am on Windows (using Docker, not Docker Windows). Not sure if that's the issue. But I cannot find a solution.

`Dockerfile.prod`

```
FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401,E722 .

# install python dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
# COPY requirements .

RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt
# RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements/prod.txt

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
# COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements/common.txt .
# COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements/prod.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Comment: Please specify an example of your Dockerfile with the FROM part. I think it is important what kind of Container image is used.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I do understand you would like to create a user and group both called "app" and the user shall be in that group, both being a system account/group.

That's possible by online using adduser

```
RUN adduser --system --group app
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:
https://github.com/mozilla-services/Dockerflow/issues/36

> Depending on the underlying distribution of the container, these
> options can be ambiguous. The options should use the full name format
> for readability.

Comment: I had tried using `groupadd` and `useradd` instead of `addgroup`/`adduser` to no avail.