# Docker writting permission denied

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a simple command with docker that read a file in my home directory and write an output file in the same directory on my local machine (`/home/userxyz/projects/data`). The `data` folder belongs to me (`userxyz`) and my group which has the same name (`userxyz`) with R/W permissions.

I built an image with a Dockerfile like so (following [How to add users to Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/how-to-add-users-to-docker-container)):

```
FROM osgeo/gdal:alpine-small-latest

RUN mkdir /usr/tmp

RUN addgroup -S userxyz \
  && adduser -S -D -h /usr/tmp userxyz userxyz \
  && chown -R userxyz:userxyz /usr/tmp

USER userxyz

WORKDIR /usr/tmp
```

and:

```
docker build -t userxyz/test .
```

I ran docker with:

```
docker run --rm -v /home/userxyz/projects/data:/usr/tmp userxyz/test gdal_translate -ot UInt32 /usr/tmp/input.tif /usr/tmp/output.tif
```

However, I still get:

```
ERROR 4: Attempt to create new tiff file `/usr/tmp/output.tif' failed: Permission denied
```

It works when I only read the file:

```
docker run --rm -v /home/userxyz/projects/data:/usr/tmp userxyz/test gdalinfo /usr/tmp/input.tif
```

Any idea what could be wrong with the writing permissions?

EDIT: when opening the data folder to read/write for "Others", the file is correctly created by `user#500100`, so I guess it's something with username attribution? How can I do so that the file is created by `userxyz` and not `user#500100`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you set the same user & group in Dockerfile with `userxyz:userxyz`, but host rootfs & container rootfs are 2 different rootfs. This means the `UID` & `GID` for same username/group name still be different.

As a result, just copy `username`, `groupname` is not enough, you also need to copy `UID`, `GID`, something like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG UID
ARG GID

RUN groupadd -g $GID userxyz
RUN useradd -m -u $UID -g $GID -s /bin/bash userxyz
```

**Build command:**

```
docker build -t abc:1 --build-arg UID=`id userxyz -u` --build-arg GID=`id userxyz -g` .
```

**Explain:**

`id userxyz -u` & `id userxyz -g` get the UID/GID on host, and pass them to build container, then `docker build` use them to set the same UID/GID with the host for `userxyz`. This will assure in container you have same permission with the host.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the user in your group **based on the group ID not on the group name**. User and group names are isolated in the container, so it won't work.

You can find the group ID in the `/etc/group` file, using this command on the host machine:

```
cat /etc/group | grep userxyz
```

Once found, you add the user to the group in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM osgeo/gdal:alpine-small-latest

RUN mkdir /usr/tmp

RUN groupadd -g $GID userxyz \
  && adduser -S -D -h /usr/tmp userxyz userxyz \
  && chown -R userxyz:userxyz /usr/tmp

USER userxyz

WORKDIR /usr/tmp
```

where you replace `$GID` by the the group ID.