# Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: Dockerfile'

Tags: docker

**Error message:**
Failed to deploy ' Dockerfile: DockerNew': com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (4294967295) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647)
at [Source: (okio.RealBufferedSource$1); line: 8, column: 34] (through reference chain: com.github.dockerjava.api.model.BuildResponseItem["errorDetail"]->com.github.dockerjava.api.model.ResponseItem$ErrorDetail["code"])

**What I am trying to do**
Run below dockerfile via Pycharm

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
CMD ["echo", "This is test application" ]
```

But it does work if i put just two lines as below

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
CMD ["echo", "This is test application" ]
```

what could be wrong with my docker file? The error message doesn't give any knowledge about how i can debug this

Comment: That's a Java exception; what code is producing it?

Comment: @DavidMaze: If I were to guess it's a java error because OP is trying to do this via Pycharm, which was written on Java if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with the `RUN adduser -D myuser` command. Probably it's waiting for input which it never receives.

Check [the answer in this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/how-to-add-users-to-docker-container) for more hints.