# Numeric value Java error when installing Docker as interpreter in Pycharm

Tags: python, java, docker, pycharm

I am trying to install Docker as a interpreter in Pycharm in order to create image from Dockerfile, but there is such an error.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (4294967295) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647) at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.github.dockerjava.api.model.WaitResponse["StatusCode"]) caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (4294967295) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647) at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.github.dockerjava.api.model.WaitResponse["StatusCode"])`

It's a java error, how can it bounded with python and how can I fix it?

Comment: Numeric value (4294967295) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647) the message seems pretty clear. You'll need to use a larger type, not int.

Comment: This is probably a bug in pycharm. Turn to their support forum and maybe write up a defect. Most likely, nobody here can help you with a bug in some 3rd party tool installing some 4th party environment setup.

Comment: But then, that message seems to come up occasionally ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466669/failed-to-deploy-unknown-dockerfile-dockerfile ...