# How to fix a mkdir error on a dockerized ap on ec2?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I have a django app based on django-cookiecutter running on an aws-ec2.
The application itself built and is running ok. This application uses the django-cities-light library.
When I run `docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python manage.py cities_light` which is the command to populate the database with countries/cities I get this error:

```
INFO 2021-11-30 15:17:36,780 cities_light 1 140562076800832 Creating /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cities_light/data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cities_light/management/commands/cities_light.py", line 145, in handle
    os.mkdir(DATA_DIR)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cities_light/data'
ERROR: 1
```

As '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cities_light/data' is inside the docker I am very confused regarding what permissions I should set and to whom.

If anyone could shed some light it will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the user inside the container has sufficient permission to `'/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cities_light/data'`.

If you have a [non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/how-to-add-users-to-docker-container) inside the container, make sure this user owns/has access to the folder. Also take a look into [this](https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vinoth for the suggestions. They were helpful.

I did a bit of reading and changing the ownership of the folder to django (user:group) by adding
`RUN chown -R django:django /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/*` to docker file fixed the problem.