# Error when opening a VSCode remote-container from a project using a Dockerfile and devcontainer.json

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, databricks

I am developing solutions in VSCode remote-containers (on the same machine). One project requires an image that is not available in VSCode container selection dialogue. The image in question is `databricksruntime/standard` which can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/databricksruntime/standard).

I needed the `Dockerfile` to go with the `devcontainer.json` definition so that the container would match that specification. I found the `Dockerfile` content by navigating to the [associated Git](https://github.com/databricks/containers/tree/master/ubuntu/standard).

```
FROM databricksruntime/dbfsfuse:experimental

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y openssh-server \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Warning: the created user has root permissions inside the container
# Warning: you still need to start the ssh process with `sudo service ssh start`
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups sudo ubuntu
```

I manually created the `devcontainer.json` to target the `Dockerfile` image when building the container.

```
{
    "name": "databricksruntime/standard",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": ".."
    },
  
    "customizations": {
      "vscode": {
        "extensions": ["dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"]
      }
    },
  
    "remoteUser": "vscode",
    "features": {
      "git": "latest",
      "git-lfs": "latest"
    }
  }
```

I selected 'Open a remote window' (bottom left of VSCode GUI) -> 'Re-open in a container'.

This raises:

> [2022-08-05T17:01:32.739Z] **Error response from daemon: manifest for databricksruntime/dbfsfuse:experimental**
> not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

> [2022-08-05T17:01:32.832Z] Stop (2843 ms): Run: docker pull databricksruntime/dbfsfuse:experimental

> [2022-08-05T17:01:32.833Z] []

> [2022-08-05T17:01:32.833Z] **Error: No such image: databricksruntime/dbfsfuse:experimental**

When we inspect the `Dockerfile` we can see that it [references another image](https://hub.docker.com/r/databricksruntime/dbfsfuse). I looked at the pull command, `docker pull databricksruntime/dbfsfuse` and ran it in a terminal. The image already exists and is visible in the Docker GUI. I noticed that the pull command does not include the suffix `:experimental` as the first line in `Dockerfile` does. I removed the suffix. The `Dockerfile` now builds.

```
[+] Building 67.0s (17/17) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 844B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4               2.0s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io           0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4@sha256:443aab4c  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/databricksruntime/dbfsfuse:lat  0.0s
 => [context dev_containers_feature_content_source] load .dockerignore     0.0s
 => => transferring dev_containers_feature_content_source: 2B              0.0s
 => [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 1/3] FROM docker.io/databricksr  0.2s
 => [context dev_containers_feature_content_source] load from client       0.1s
 => => transferring dev_containers_feature_content_source: 270.81kB        0.0s
 => [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 2/3] RUN apt-get update   && a  22.2s
 => [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 3/3] RUN useradd --create-home   0.6s
 => [stage-1 1/2] COPY --from=dev_containers_feature_content_source . /tm  0.1s
 => [stage-1 2/2] RUN cd /tmp/build-features/local-cache && chmod +x ./i  41.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:aa97f07c0ec4c2e8ae9d512da1bc45b63b32396266134  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/vsc-parallelloadsscd4-d62f8c81c6e595b4  0.0s
 => exporting cache                                                        0.0s
 => => preparing build cache for export                                    0.0s
```

The container is started and then tested. **Another error** is raised:

> [70182 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 126, signal: null)

> [70182 ms] unable to find user vscode: no matching entries in passwd file

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.189Z] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.189Z] Stdin closed! [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]

> Error: An error occurred setting up the container.
> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]     at HR
> (c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:239:2183)
> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]     at tb
> (c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:239:2121)

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]     at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]
> at async QR
> (c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:2006)

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]     at async cb
> (c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:3110)

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]     at async i_
> (c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:13194)

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.190Z]     at async n_
> (c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:12950)

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.200Z] Stop (69586 ms): Run:
> C:\Users\mruser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
> c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js
> up --user-data-folder
> c:\Users\mruser\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data
> --workspace-folder c:\Users\mruser\source\repos\data\ParallelLoadsScd4 --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mruser\source\repos\data\ParallelLoadsScd4
> --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mruser\source\repos\data\ParallelLoadsScd4.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
> --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true
> --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.200Z] Exit code 1

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.204Z] Command failed:
> **C:\Users\mruser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe**
> c:\Users\mruser.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.241.3\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js
> up --user-data-folder
> c:\Users\mruser\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data
> --workspace-folder c:\Users\mruser\source\repos\data\ParallelLoadsScd4 --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=c:\Users\mruser\source\repos\data\ParallelLoadsScd4
> --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\mruser\source\repos\data\ParallelLoadsScd4.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
> --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true
> --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true

> [2022-08-05T17:10:05.204Z] Exit code 1

A **user is missing for VSCode**. This user is presumably so that VSCode local can interface with VSCode remote. This user is defined as `"remoteUser": "vscode",` in `devcontainer.json`.

I have seen this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/how-to-add-users-to-docker-container). I am not sure how to define this user, more reading needed.

I modified the `devcontainer.json` to set the **vscode user** to `"remoteUser": "root",`. This seems wrong. The container runs now. I referenced [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-nonroot-user).

I am *still* looking into this. Has anyone faced this issue? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the error for me:

```
sudo snap install docker
```