# How to Create a User in a Docker Image with the Proper File Permissions

Tags: permissions, dockerfile

I have a Python package called `mypackage` that I want to install in a Docker image. I want to create a user called `myuser` in the image instead of just running things as root. Here is my Dockerfile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3

# Create a user.
RUN useradd --user-group --system --no-log-init --create-home myuser
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser
USER myuser

# Install the package.
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /home/myuser
COPY . ./mypackage
RUN pip install /home/myuser/mypackage && rm -rf /home/myuser/mypackage
```

This fails on the `pip install` because `myuser` does not have write permissions in the `/home/myuser` folder. If I build the image without the last step and then go look at the directory permissions everything is still owned by root.

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 16 14:21 mypackage
```

I assume the mistake is with the `chown` statement, but I copied that logic from [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701930/how-to-add-users-to-docker-container) and it looks right to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the user:group in the COPY command,
see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] ["<src>",... "<dest>"]
```

The fixed Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# Create a user.
RUN useradd --user-group --system --no-log-init --create-home myuser
USER myuser

# Install the package.
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /home/myuser
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser . ./mypackage
RUN pip install /home/myuser/mypackage && rm -rf /home/myuser/mypackage
```